# datepicker with ngdialog in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, ng-dialog

Is there any datepicker angularjs module available which can be used with ngdialog and works well with all three browsers (IE, FF and Chrome)?

I know I might be asking *duplicate* question but I have gone through lot of stackoverflow threads and found some angular datepickers which aren't seem to be working well(css issues) with ngdialog or above mentioned browsers.

720kb datepicker seems to be working fine in all three browsers but the css gets messed up badly when I use it with ngdialog. Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIhtw.jpg

**Update:** For now, ended up using jquery datepicker which works in all browsers. I am quite unsure if it is a bad idea to use jquery with angularjs.

Answer (score 2):

check this out for angularjs date picker,but not sure if it will work fine with ngdialog

http://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/

Comment: Thanks but I tried this already. css gets messed up badly when I use it with ngdialog. Screenshot - http://imgur.com/AlvvflK Any thoughts on why it might be breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Try following link.There are many functionalities.
Search for Datepicker.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular in my application.

There is just one small issue you have to fix:
The `ngDialog` css-class has a z-index of 10000 and the datepicker let's say only 5000. You have to change the z-index to 1000. Otherwise you can't see the datepicker because it lays behind the dialog.